# What is the difference between --parameter and -parameter?

Tags: git, bash, command-line-arguments

I used git for some time now, but mostly I preferred the integration with Intelij IDEA. Now, in order to extend my knowledge and understanding of the system I decided to use the command line more. What I observed is that there are two types of parameters:

```
--parameter and -parameter
```

for example:

```
 git commit --amend -m "New commit message"
```

I observed the same approach on some linux tools.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

-- is used for multicharacter arguments, - is for singlecharacter arguments.

For example, those are in many programs equivalent:

`program -h` <-> `program --help`

The reason is, if you use -, you can specify many arguments at once, for example:

`ls -lah` gives a list of the directory content, all content, human-readible.

It needs to know that you don't mean the argument "--lah", but "-l -a -h"

Comment: I'd also note that this is [GNU conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html) based on POSIX. However, there are programs not following it, for exaple [mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/man/en/mplayer.1.html)